# Any way to start IIS App (Website) automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core website hosted on IIS. This site uses a IHostedService added with services.AddHostedService method.
I set up IIS App pool to "AlwaysRunning" and "0" to Idle time-out.

The thing I need is to run this service right after the AppPool (and IIS) starts. However, it starts after I access any page of it. I understand, that this case is when app is created or whatever.

Is there any way to start the website automatically and keep it online?

Comment: Please remove this as a duplicate. That answer only provides half the information. Setting `Start Mode` to `Always Running` only effects the app pool. The ASP.NET Core application will still not be 'warmed up'. Hence the reason you need to set the hosting model to `InProcess`.

Comment: The answer given in a related topic does not works on my issue. Process starts, but with an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with IIS 8 and ASP.NET Core 2.2.

In IIS you'll need to set the `Start Mode` to `Always Running`
*https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/09/iis-8-whats-new-application-pool-settings/*

Then in your `.csproj` you'll need to add `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`
*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model*

If you're interested here is the Github issue for this feature:
*https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3849*

Answer (score 0):

Register at any ping/check/monitoring free service, and it will make request to your site every 5/10/15 minutes